# Accessing Yahoo YQL finance query

Tags: json, yql, yahoo-finance

I am receiving an error when trying to use the yql statement.  The console says there is a syntax error, but I do not see an error.  I have posted all of the code so it can be copy and pasted to repeat the error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
<title>Finances</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function start(){
    getData();
  //  document.getElementById('link1').click();
}
function getData() {
var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql";
var symbol = $("#symbol").val();
var dateInput = $("#dateInput").val();
var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = '"symbol"' and startDate = '"dateInput"' and endDate = '"dateInput"'");



$.getJSON(url, '?q=' + data + "&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys")
    .done(function (data) {

         $("#name").text(data.query.results.quote.Symbol);
         $("#date").text(data.query.results.quote.Date);
         $("#close").text( data.query.results.quote.Close);


}).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        $("#result").text('Request failed: ' + err);
});
}
function SendRequest()
{
    getData();
   // document.getElementById('link1').click();
}   

function CheckEnter(e)
{
    if ((e.keyCode && e.keyCode==13) || (e.which && e.which==13)) {
        return SendRequest();
    }
    return true;
}       

</script>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0px;" bgcolor="#678fc2" onload="start();">

<table width="90%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
<tbody>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td class="normalText" align="left">
        <label>Date</label>
        <input name="date" id="dateInput"  value="2010-07-17" type="text" />
        <br/>
        <label>Ticker Symbol</label>
        <input name="txtQuote" id="symbol" onkeypress="return CheckEnter(event);" value="YHOO" type="text" />
        <input name="button" type="button" id="btnQuote" onclick="return SendRequest();" value="Get Quotes" />
        <br />

        <div id="service" style="padding:10px 0;">
            <table style="border: 1px solid black;" width="770">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 2px;">
                    <td>Symbol</td>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td>Closing Price</td>
                </tr>
                <tr style="font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; padding: 0px 2px;">
                    <td id="name"></td>
                    <td id="date"></td>
                    <td id="close"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <br /><br />
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error I was having.  This is the correct line now:

```
var data = encodeURIComponent("select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = '" + symbol + "' and startDate = '" + dateInput + "' and endDate = '" + dateInput + "'");
```